# Target class [HomeController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Target class [HomeController] does not exist.

i'm using laravel in web.php i have this code :

```
Route::get('/home','HomeController@home' )->name('home');
Route::get('/about','HomeController@about' )->name('about');
```

in file homeController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function home(){
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: It is of the outmost importance that you read the documentation, also taking into account the Laravel version you are using. Because you are not a magician nor have 500 IQ, you must read it, there is no other way of learning **the basic features** the framework has and provides. So please, have a look at the beautiful handcrafted documentation before posting already existing questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Laravel are you using? If you are using Laravel 10 (the latest), you should import the controller and use it like this:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
 
Route::get('/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

You can read more in details in the official documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers